# in a program ...A,B and C.You have to out put the average of these 3 numbers Average of N numbers is sum of those numbers divided by N) JAVA

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class JavaBasics {
    public static void main(String agrs[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int c = sc.nextInt();

        int avg = a + b + c / 3;

        System.out.println(avg);
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question. Take a tour of the [help], particularly [ask].

Comment: What is your question? Please edit that into your post. And while you're at it, please fix your formatting. (There is a preview feature when posting a question. There is no need to post a question that looks as ugly as this one)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a place to ask questions. It is expected, when you ask a question,  there actually *is* a question. Please take the advice in the comment from Rogue. It might also help to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: In the interest of saving time, there is a problem with your code. [Java operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) generally follows the rules of mathematics. You might also be interested in looking into the difference between floating point division and integer division. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/int-division-why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0 for one.

Answer (score 1):

Though your question could be cleaer, the only apparent issue lies with this line:

```
int avg = a + b + c / 3;
```

Java's operator precedence rules (which match those in math in this case) mean this is equivalent to:

```
int avg = a + b + (c / 3);
```

Rather than the desired sum of a, b, and c divided by three to get the average.

```
int avg = (a + b + c) / 3;
```

However, bear in mind that this is doing *integer* math. If you want a floating point average, you will need to divide your sum by a floating point number.

```
double avg = (a + b + c) / 3.0;
```

For inputs of 4, 2 and 1 this now gives 2.333... whereas the former would give an average of 2.

Comment: Integer arithmetic is probably not what is wanted. The average of 2, 2, and 1 will be 1. `double avg = (a + b + c) / 3.0;` is probably what is wanted.